# How to bake a simple material to a UV unwrapped texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking

I am a beginner learner in blender and I have been learning about texturing and UV unwrapping.

In this Brackey's tutorial, he adds basic materials before UV unwrapping the model. Similarly, I have accomplished this. However, after unwrapping, he manages to make the materials that have already been added into a texture that can be exported to Photoshop, to add greater detail.

I want to do the same thing, but I am using a much newer version of Blender.

Here is a link to the video where he adds the materials (at around 5:30):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYKQwMc-WdE

Here is a link to the video where he starts unwrapping:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLEpjSFHl4o

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In the second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLEpjSFHl4o&ab_channel=Brackeys) you attached, at around 6 minutes he bakes the texture. You need to do the same thing, and export it as an image if you want to bring it into photoshop.
Since you said you use a newer version of Blender, I assume you use one of them up from 2.8. So you need to set the Render Engine to Cycles, then a Bake option will appear for you. And that is the place where you can bake any type of texture.

[image]

Comment: Just got it work. Thanks man! :)